# TSQL - Deleting with Inner Joins and multiple conditions

Tags: t-sql

My question is a variation on one already asked and answered (TSQL Delete Using Inner Joins) but I have a different level of complexity and I couldn't see a solution to it.

My requirement is to delete Special Prices which haven't been accessed in 90 days. Special Prices are keyed on Customer ID and Product ID and the products have to matched to a Customer Order Detail table which also contains a Customer ID and a Product ID. I want to write one function that will look at the Special Price table for each Customer, compare each Product for that Customer with the Customer Order Detail table and if the Maximum Order Date is more than 90 days earlier than today, delete it from the Special Price table.

I know I can use a CURSOR (slow but effective) but would prefer to have a single query like the one in the TSQL Delete Using Inner Joins example.  Any ideas and/or is more information required?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot dig more on the situation of  your system but i think and if it is ok for you, check `MERGE STATEMENT`, it might be a help instead of using cursors. check this Link [MERGE STATEMENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: why downvote peter? are you sure of downvoting this?